# How to retrieve UserDefaults because cells are empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, nsuserdefaults

I made a struct dictionary to get the user title and URL, and then I store them on the phone but when I come to retrieve the data in `cellForRow` method the cell label is empty, what should appear is the title.(`tableView` starts off empty until user starts to populate it with the `AddArticle` action)

So my question is if I'm doing it right because the cell label just turns out nil?

Struct Dictionary:

```
struct AddMagazine {
    let rssUrl: String
    let title: String

    init(dict: [String : String]){
        title = dict["title"] ?? ""
        rssUrl = dict["rssUrl"] ?? ""

    }
}
var userMagazineTitle = [AddMagazine]()
```

Getting values from textField:

```
@IBAction func AddArticle(_ sender: Any) {
            animateIn()
            tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }

        func addArticleTitle() {

            let UserMagazines = AddMagazine.init(dict: ["title": RssTitle.text!, "rssUrl": RssText.text!])
            let storedRssUrl = UserMagazines.rssUrl
            self.dataString = storedRssUrl

            //setting
            defaults.set(dataString, forKey: "storedArray")

            userMagazineTitle.append(UserMagazines)
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
```

Trying to retrieve title here:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! MyFeedTableViewCell

        let headlineName = defaults.object(forKey: "storedArray") as? AddMagazine
        cell.myHeadline.text = headlineName?.title

        cell.indentationLevel = 3
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a single line where you are reading your UserDefaults file.  Plus, the word retireve in your title doesn't exist.

Comment: Apart from your issue `UserDefaults` is the wrong place for temporary data related to a table view data source.

Answer (score 0):

You’re storing a String object in defaults for “storedArray” but then you typecast it to an AddMagazine when you read it from defaults. Change what you store or read it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Joakim Danielson. You are storing storedRssUrl which is a string into userdefaults and while retrieving you are type casting as AddMagazine hence it will be nil.

```
self.dataString = storedRssUrl
//setting
defaults.set(dataString, forKey: "storedArray") --> Here you are storing string

let headlineName = defaults.object(forKey: "storedArray") as? AddMagazine --> Here you are fetching as AddMagazine.

//It should be like this
let headlineName = defaults.object(forKey: "storedArray") as? String
```

Comment: It should be even `defaults.string(forKey` 

Comment: @vadian, yup better than casting.